# Physical server web hosting load test

Tags: webserver, hosting-services

I have 4 high configuration Dell R730 server.
Configuration noted below.

```
CPU: 2XIntel Xeon E5-2643 v3 3.4GHz,20M Cache,9.60GT/s QPI,Turbo,HT,6C/12T (135W) Max Mem 2133MHz
Memory: 192GB (12x 16GB ) RDIMM, 2133 MT/s, upgradeable to 768GB
HDD: 48 TB (6 x8TB)  7.2K RPM NLSAS 12Gbps 512e 3.5in Hot-plug Hard Drive
Ethernet port: 4 (1Gig each)
```

I want to use these for web host business. and I want to host here approximately 15k-20k site.
I need to use this 4 server as DC/DR system. service must be high available. so I have to use load balancing and others clustering techniques.
Please anyone suggest me the design.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know where to start you probably don't want to try an roll-your-own with native Linux tools. Would be best to get CloudLinux from cPanel, which has all that you'd need to host that number of sites for about US$1K a year: https://www.cloudlinux.com/all-products/product-overview/cloudlinuxos

Comment: I am using cPanel for enterprise level mail solution. but I am asking for high availability, redundancy and disaster recovery. with this number of servers how can I perform this.